# specify fields to be serialized with JSON

Tags: c#, json, serialization

it's about json serialization. 
Here is the situation:

```
public class Book
{       
    public string BookName { get; set; }
    public decimal BookPrice { get; set; }       
    public string AuthorName { get; set; }
    public int AuthorAge { get; set; }
    public string AuthorCountry { get; set; }
}

public class MyBag{
   public string owner {get; set;}
   public Book math_Book{get; set;}

}
```

Book has several fields, but not all are needed to serialiazed. for example, I only want to know the BookName and BookPrice. and I'd like to specific the fields name and customize jsonPropertyAttribute. Just like this:

```
 public class MyBag{
   public string owner {get; set;}
   [JsonProperty(serializedFields("BookName", "BookPrice"))]
   public Book math_Book{get; set;}
}
```

Does Json has the feature to customize JsonPropertyAttribute ? or how can I do to make this work ?

Since I don‘t find how to create customize JsonPropertyAttribute， I create customizeAttribute for Csharp object，like this：

```
    public class SerializedFieldsAttribute : Attribute
{
    private IList<string> _serializedFields = new List<string>();
    public SerializedFieldsAttribute(string[] fields)
    {
        _serializedFields = fields;
    }

    public IList<string> GetFields()
    {
        return _serializedFields;
    }

}

 public class MyBag
{
    public String Owner { get; set; }
    [SerializedFieldsAttribute(new string[] { "BookName", "BookPrice" })]
    public Book MyBook { get; set; }
}
```

now I can get the SerializedFieldsAttribute， but how can I do to make

```
var book = new Book
            {
                BookName = "Yu Wen",
                BookPrice = 56,
                AuthorName = "Li QingZhao",
                AuthorAge = 28,
                AuthorCountry = "Song"
            };
        var bag = new MyBag
            {
                Owner = "shoren",
                MyBook = book
            };
```

to

```
    {
       "Owner": "shoren",
       "MyBook": {
            "BookName": "Yu Wen",
            "BookPrice": 56.0,
       }
    }
```

Comment: Try this [link](http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/serialize-only-specific-class). Let me know if it helps.

Comment: thanks, but it's not my problem. I would like the Json serializer to parse the custom attribute. For example, a is an instance of Class A,string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a); the result would show that myData only has two fields, DataVersion and DataId.

Answer (score 2):

Try [ScriptIgnoreAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute.aspx)

```
public class Book
{       
    public string BookName { get; set; }
    public decimal BookPrice { get; set; }       

    [ScriptIgnore]
    public string AuthorName { get; set; }

    [ScriptIgnore]
    public int AuthorAge { get; set; }

    [ScriptIgnore] 
    public string AuthorCountry { get; set; }
}
```

More appropriate solution is to create `BookViewModel` class only with two fields you need, map your `Book` instanse to `BookViewModel` instance in controller and pass view model instead of model to view (serilalize to json).